# media query overriding the desktop styles

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, media-queries

I am designing a email template for my application.

For a particular type of content I need it to be displayed as table in desktop and normal content in handhold devices. While sending a mail from my application in local I am getting the normal view instead of table in my desktop. The media query are overriding.

**desktop.css**

```
.list{
width: 90%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
.list td{
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
.list th {
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
.hide-show{
display: none;
}
```

**mobile.css**

```
.list{
    width: 100% !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.list td{
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.list th{
    display: none !important;
}
.hide-show{
    display: inline !important;
}
```

**email_template.html.erb**

```
<table class="list">
  <tr>
    <th>product</th>
    <th> Number of items</th>
  </tr>
  <% product.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="m-bold" style="padding: 10px"><%= product.full_name %></td>
        <td style="padding: 10px"><span class="hide-show">No.of.items:</span><%= product.count %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Edit: updated with `@media`:

**mobile.css**

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .list{
        width: 100% !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
    .list td{
        width: 100% !important;
        display: block !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
    .list th{
        display: none !important;
    }
    .hide-show{
        display: inline !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  You may also find [Twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) quite helpfult

Comment: @MrCoder could you elaborate  your question?

Comment: using jsfiddle allows us to see what you're having problems with *visually*. It also helps with our understanding of the problem you are facing. It allows you to paste your html/css markup as well, which helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `!important` whenever possible. You don't need `!important` within media-queries unless the original styles have it, then you would need to use it to override the original.

So first off show us the actual media queries that include @media screen and such.

Try removing all the `!important` from your css and test again.

Comment: While this may be useful to the OP, it does not answer the question. To critique or request clarification, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I need 50 reputation to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the mobile css is at the top of the css page then tablet and desktop after. This should stop the override problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using roadie gem and wrote different style sheets for desktop and mobile styles.

Comment: you could add a media query to the desktop file with min and max width

     @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1600px)
ofc change as needed.